# Why typescript error: 'const' declarations are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6 and higher

Tags: visual-studio-2013, typescript, typescript1.8

After installing Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (been running VS2013) I'm getting the typescript error: "'const' declarations are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6 and higher" when I build my solution in VS2013.

In the VS2013 Output window I get:
error TS1154: Build:'const' declarations are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6 and higher.
... with direct reference to the code: "const styles = [{ "featureT"

If I build the solution with VS2015 I'm getting the same error:
Build:'const' declarations are only available when targeting ECMAScript 6 and higher.   C:\Projects\appts.ts, Project.Web, 152.

I'm running typescript 1.8 (c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8) (not sure which sub version 1.8.?) and the VS2013 solution file points to v1.8 (1.8)

The code that produce the error:

```
const styles = [{ "featureType": "landscape" }];
```

The code compiles if changed to:

```
var styles = [{ "featureType": "landscape" }];
```

If I change the VS2015 setting "Project Properties" > "TypeScript Build" > "General" > "ECMAScript version" from "ECMAScript 5" to "ECMAScript 6" I'm getting the error: "tsc.exe" exited with code 1

Why am I getting the compile error message?

NB JetBrains Resharper 2016.1.2 is installed (don't know if it matters)

Comment: Most likely because you're not compiling to ES6?

Comment: are you using Resharp?

Comment: @Invernomuto Resharper 2016.1.2 is running

Comment: set the Typescript language level to the latest available under Resharper -> Options -> Code Editing -> TypeScript -> Inspections -> Typescript

Comment: @Invernomuto I tried changing the Options -> Code Editing -> TypeScript -> Inspections from "default" to "1.8" with no effect.

Comment: @Bergi If I change setting "Project Properties" > "TypeScript Build" > "General" > "ECMAScript version" from "ECMAScript 5" to "ECMAScript 6" I'm getting the error: "tsc.exe" exited with code 1